# regexp in vim visual selection, up to the last character selected

Tags: regex, vim, selected

Given this line in vim:

```
The cat is sleepy.
```

I want to replace "sleepy" by "black" (of course this is for sake of simplicity, i'm actually editing C code)

When cursor is at the beginning of the line, i type "/sle" to make it go to the beginning of "sleepy"
Then <kbd>v</kbd>, then <kbd>e</kbd>

The word "sleepy" is now fully selected.
Then i type ":s/\%V.*\%V/black/"

And instead of having:

```
The cat is black.
```

It gives:

```
The cat is blacky.
```

The last character visually selected is not considered as part of the selection, or maybe i'm not using \%V correctly.

How can i make pattern matching works in **exactly** my visual selection ?

Comment: This probably isn't what you're looking for, but `/sle[return]dwiblack[esc]` gets the desired result in fewer characters than the visual mode pattern matching solution.

Comment: I know, this is a simplified example to better explain my real question.

Comment: You should give us a more realistic example, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add one character after `\%V`:

```
/\%V.*\%V.
```

. If selection contains more then one line you will have to use `\%V\_.*\%V\_.`.

There is also another trick:

```
/\%V\_.\{-}\%V\@!
```

(multiline version). This makes use of non-greedy matches and negative look-ahead: first (`\{-}`) to make sure it operates only on selection, second (`\@!`, specifically `\%V\@!`) to make sure there is no visual selection after the last character.

If you have more complex pattern and cannot make it non-greedy or put one character after last `\%V` there is another solution, which is way to slow though:

```
/\%V\_.*\%(\%V\_.\)\@<=
```

(multiline version again). It uses positive look-behind to make sure that last character is still inside visual selection.

Comment: Why the need for a non-greedy match? Doesn't `/\%V{pattern}\%(\%V.\)\@<=` work? Also, Vim seems to handle `:set selection=exclusive` without adapting the offset.

Comment: @IngoKarkat When `selection=exclusive` `ve` selects one more character, but `\%V` ends earlier. It should not be a concern if you adapt pattern to handling certain motions like `e`, but it should if you want to use search to highlight exactly the same text as `gv` will. Your pattern also works, but it is my third with `\%V\@!` removed: no idea why I did not manage to get that this part is not needed.

Comment: @IngoKarkat And in the second pattern non-greedy is needed because `\%V\@!` matches anywhere but inside the match.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I am wrong about `exclusive`: the last character is not highlighted *as a part of selection*, it is highlighted *as a cursor position*. It became clear as I checked what is highlighted when I press `o`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by "Vim seems to handle it". Thanks for delving into this and clarifying!